# Как правильно задать тег meta og:image?

Tags: html, css, html5

Подскажите как правильно прописать свойства на тег:
У меня лого 1200*1200, а в facebook 1200x630

```html
<meta property="og:image"
      content="public/images/logo.png"   <!-- Лого 1200*1200 -->
      style="max-width:auto;
             height:50% ;">
```

Правильно ли я прописал? мне нужно чтоб картинка 1200 на 1200 разместилась на 1200x630

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Любые css для meta **неприменимы в принципе**, как и для других элементов внутри head. Подготовьте превью для соц.сетей программно.

Comment: Ответ верный, но заявление про head и вложенные элементы несколько преувеличено: https://jsfiddle.net/n5LuLkkk/.

Comment: @Qwertiy а такое поведение хак или в стандарте прописано?)

Comment: @andreymal, не знаю, но вроде логично, что если есть элемент, то его можно показать? Вроде все браузеры реализуют просто через что-то в духе `head, style, script { display: none; }` в браузерных стилях?

Comment: Eduard Misk, что Вы имеете ввиду под прописать програмно?

Comment: а почему не держать отдельное пэнэже в 1200х630???

Comment: Kirill Korushkin, это, конечно хороший вариант (я скорее всего к нему и прибегну), но меня заинтересовали слова Eduard Misk, чтоб сделать это программно. Поэтому хочется узнать и такой вариант

Comment: @Александр, использовать api примерно такого характера https://kraken.io/docs/image-resizing или на моей практике с вордпресс - использовать еще один размер кадрирования и подставлять в источник. Не уверен, можно ли подключать изображения для og:image извне, потому такие кадры лучше хранить в пределах домена.

Comment: @Qwertiy, согласен, но индекс-боты смогут понять такой тон неверно)